# R tidyverse how to do two pivot_longer after each other instead of a single one

Tags: r, pivot, tidyr

Assume the following data:

```
structure(list(uuid = c("abc", "def", "hij"), Q1r1 = c(0L, 1L, 
1L), Q1r2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), Q1r3 = c(1L, 0L, 1L), Q2r1c1 = c(4L, 
3L, 5L), Q2r1c2 = 2:4, Q2r1c3 = c(1L, 5L, 2L), Q2r2c1 = c(3L, 
3L, 4L), Q2r2c2 = c(2L, 5L, 4L), Q2r2c3 = c(1L, 4L, 5L), Q3r1 = c(5L, 
9L, 7L), Q3r2 = c(10L, 3L, 8L), Q3r3 = c(6L, 8L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

which gives:

```
  uuid Q1r1 Q1r2 Q1r3 Q2r1c1 Q2r1c2 Q2r1c3 Q2r2c1 Q2r2c2 Q2r2c3 Q3r1 Q3r2 Q3r3
1  abc    0    1    1      4      2      1      3      2      1    5   10    6
2  def    1    1    0      3      3      5      3      5      4    9    3    8
3  hij    1    1    1      5      4      2      4      4      5    7    8    5
```

Now assume that I want to pivot_longer the data for all Q1 and Q3 columns (where r1, r2 and r3 in these columns indicate the to-be-created rows).

This is relatively straightforward with:

```
dat %>%
  pivot_longer(cols      = c(starts_with("Q1"), starts_with("Q3")),
               names_sep = "r",
               names_to  = c('.value', 'brand’))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 10
  uuid  Q2r1c1 Q2r1c2 Q2r1c3 Q2r2c1 Q2r2c2 Q2r2c3 brand    Q1    Q3
  <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int> <chr> <int> <int>
1 abc        4      2      1      3      2      1 1         0     5
2 abc        4      2      1      3      2      1 2         1    10
3 abc        4      2      1      3      2      1 3         1     6
4 def        3      3      5      3      5      4 1         1     9
5 def        3      3      5      3      5      4 2         1     3
6 def        3      3      5      3      5      4 3         0     8
7 hij        5      4      2      4      4      5 1         1     7
8 hij        5      4      2      4      4      5 2         1     8
9 hij        5      4      2      4      4      5 3         1     5
```

**Now, here's my question: would there also be a way to separate both pivotings from each other, i.e. first pivot_longer Q1 and then afterwards pivot_longer Q3?**

The reason I'm asking is that alternatively I also want to pivot Q2 and Q3 (but in Q2 the row identifiers are c1, c2, c3 and I want to have two resulting columns Q2r1 and Q2r2 after pivoting_longer, whereas the row identifier is r1, r2, r3 for Q3, so the above simple code with `names_sep` and `names_to` doesn't work anymore). A colleague told me that in other software you can kind of concatenate the single pivot_longers so I'm wondering if the same is possible in R.

**Note: I know how to do the pivoting for Q2 and Q3 in one round. I really just want to know if it is possible to split up the pivotings and do them one after the other.**

The expected output from the first example where I pivot on Q1 and Q3 would be:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 10
  uuid  Q2r1c1 Q2r1c2 Q2r1c3 Q2r2c1 Q2r2c2 Q2r2c3 brand    Q1    Q3
  <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int> <chr> <int> <int>
1 abc        4      2      1      3      2      1 1         0     5
2 abc        4      2      1      3      2      1 2         1    10
3 abc        4      2      1      3      2      1 3         1     6
4 def        3      3      5      3      5      4 1         1     9
5 def        3      3      5      3      5      4 2         1     3
6 def        3      3      5      3      5      4 3         0     8
7 hij        5      4      2      4      4      5 1         1     7
8 hij        5      4      2      4      4      5 2         1     8
9 hij        5      4      2      4      4      5 3         1     5
```

The desired output from the second example where I want to pivot on Q2 and Q3 would be:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 8
  uuid   Q1r1  Q1r2  Q1r3 brand   Q2r1  Q2r2    Q3
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <chr>  <int> <int> <int>
1 abc       0     1     1 brand1     4     3     5
2 abc       0     1     1 brand2     2     2    10
3 abc       0     1     1 brand3     1     1     6
4 def       1     1     0 brand1     3     3     9
5 def       1     1     0 brand2     3     5     3
6 def       1     1     0 brand3     5     4     8
7 hij       1     1     1 brand1     5     4     7
8 hij       1     1     1 brand2     4     4     8
9 hij       1     1     1 brand3     2     5     5
```

Comment: Can you post your desired output?

Comment: For the first example (where I pivot_longer Q1 and Q3) the output is really just the one you would get when running my pivoting code. However, I'll update my post.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after understanding the question better, the only answers I can think of are hackish. You mentioned one in the comments; here is another. This revolves around having flexible regex for selecting columns. Then it joins the dataframes together via `Reduce()` (or you can swap if for `purrr::reduce()` if you prefer). Also, note, this is performing the wide-to long multiple independent times (and combining) instead of doing it sequentially.

```
col_starts <- c("Q2", "Q3")

lapply(col_starts, function(x) {
  
  df %>%
    pivot_longer(matches(paste0("^", x)),
                 names_pattern = "(Q\\d.*)[rc](\\d)$",
                 names_to = c(".value", "brand")) %>%
    select(uuid, brand:ncol(.), everything(), -matches(paste0("^", setdiff(col_starts, x), collapse = "|")))
  
}) %>% Reduce(function(x, y) left_join(x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y))), .)
# A tibble: 9 x 8
  uuid  brand  Q2r1  Q2r2  Q1r1  Q1r2  Q1r3    Q3
  <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 abc   1         4     3     0     1     1     5
2 abc   2         2     2     0     1     1    10
3 abc   3         1     1     0     1     1     6
4 def   1         3     3     1     1     0     9
5 def   2         3     5     1     1     0     3
6 def   3         5     4     1     1     0     8
7 hij   1         5     4     1     1     1     7
8 hij   2         4     4     1     1     1     8
9 hij   3         2     5     1     1     1     5
```

Here is a version that only keeps the `uuid`, `brand` and derived columns (it is a little easier to read imo)

```
lapply(c("Q2", "Q3"), function(x) {
  
  df %>%
    pivot_longer(matches(paste0("^", x)),
                 names_pattern = "(Q\\d.*)[rc](\\d)$",
                 names_to = c(".value", "brand")) %>%
    select(uuid, brand, starts_with(x))
  
}) %>% Reduce(function(x, y) left_join(x, y, by = c("uuid", "brand")), .)
```

Comment: Thanks for your code above. However, the example you mentioned is one where you would get to the results in one pipe, i.e. you just call the pivot_longer one time. However, what I wanted was to know if there is a way to get to the same results when calling the pivot_longer several times. So let's say the first call pivots on Q2, which gives you the `brand` and `Q2r1` and `Q2r2` columns. But Q3r1, Q3r2 and Q3r3 are left in their original format (like Q1r1, Q1r2, Q1r3). So question is, once you have this temporary reshaped data set, how could you ADD another pivot_longer call on Q3r1-Q3r3...

Comment: ...and still get the desired output I mentioned above? I know it is unnecessary to to several pivot calls for this example. It is really more about the question if it is possible. Because sometimes people might find it easier if they can split up their pipes and do things step by step.

Comment: I think I understand, you want the end result but you want it in several steps. It may be possible but I do not think with two subsequent calls to `pivot_longer()`, because with the second call you are not making the data longer at all. I will think about it and delete this answer later if I cannot come up with anything additional.

Comment: Exactly, this is what I want to achieve. I also already thought that two subsequent pivot-longers won‘t work. I‘m also fine if the answer to my question is „no, not possible“. But maybe I‘m missing  an option.

Comment: I guess one way how we could achieve that is to a) group by uuid (the id variable), then sort the data set by the brand variable, then count how many Q3 colums there are and then create a new column that takes the value of the first Q3 column and first row + the second Q3 column‘s value from second row + third Q3 column‘s value from third row. But although technically this works I wouldn‘t necessarily call this a solution (it‘s more a dirty hack than anything else).

Comment: Yeah i thought about that as well (the hack, that is). Also thought about using `lapply()` with a common pattern w/ `Reduce()`, but it is only clean if you want to keep only your output columns (otherwise it gets a bit messy).

Comment: Thanks for putting together this...workaround. But to summarize I'd say there is no straightforward way to "concatenate" several pivots in the fashion I've outlined. At least not in a way that it would look more clean or structured and might be easier to understand for beginners. This totally makes sense keeping in mind how the pivot_longer works (as you mentioned, the second pivot_longer wouldn't be a pivot_longer anymore).

Comment: Yup, I'd agree--no straightforward way to chain `pivot_longer()'s together.